# Best/usual practices for android app directories

Tags: android, user-interface, directory

Is there any sort of consensus on creating/using directories for storing/accessing data for android apps.

For example on windows a new application (say MyApp) would go in the "Program files" directory in a new "MyApp" directory.

I'm writing an app that allows the user to analyse photo and xml files. Is it usual to expect MyApp to just look for those files in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), require the user to move the photos/xmls to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()/MyApp or something else? Should you always just provide a file explorer to look anywhere on the device?

I can do any of the above  means of accessing but it's better to stick with the user's expectations.

Any pointer to a UI preferred practices would be useful (assuming they're widely followed).

Answer (score 0):

To store your pictures (assuming you are using API >= 8), you should use:

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) which contains an example.
If you want to keep your images in a separate folder you can create one named after your package name inside this one.

Otherwise, if you are using API <= 7, use [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to obtain the root of the tree from where you should start looking for images.

Comment: The app is compatible back to api 3. Please note this is not for xml/photos created by the app but for those that are available on the device.